# OSX and CVSROOT

Tags: service, cvs, inetd, xinetd

I am using on a computer OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.5 server.  I want to configure CVS on it so that other computers can use that repository later.

1. Can someone explain me ho to configure and start xinetd (preferably) or inetd.  The directory /etc/xinetd.d is empty (means no services use it).   When I type "/System/Library/StartupItems/IPServices/IPServices start"  I get "command not found".
2. How to configure Internet Services to make sure that they know where is my CVS repository and on what port to listen => need to configure port 2401.
3. I dont find any inetd.conf file in  /etc - why ?
   Thk.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X uses launchd to start services.  Here's a [link](http://alvinalexander.com/mac-os-x/launchd-examples-launchd-plist-file-examples-mac) with an example of creating a launchd job.

However, it might make more sense to use cvs over ssh rather than running pserver.  It provides encryption for the usernames & passwords.